# Print the output of a function in terminal

Tags: r, linux, function, terminal, output

I have defined the following function in R.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
fahr_to_kelvin <- function(temp) {
  kelvin <- ((temp - 32) * (5 / 9)) + 273.15
  print("Hello World")
  return(kelvin)
}
```

When I enter `fahr_to_kelvin(32)` in the R console, it returns  273.15 (without printing "Hello World"! I do not know why!) Anyway, I try to code below:

```
chmod +x ~/tuning1/Fun1.R
~/tuning1/Fun1.R
```

However, nothing appears in the terminal (with no error). Would you please help me why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the script file only contains the declaration of the function, without the actual invocation.

Add a new line to the end of the script to invoke the function, or better read the argument from command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
fahr_to_kelvin <- function(temp) {
  kelvin <- ((temp - 32) * (5 / 9)) + 273.15
  print("Hello World")
  return(kelvin)
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
if (length(args) > 0) {
  fahr_to_kelvin(as.numeric(args[1]))
} else {
   print("Supply one argument as the numeric value: usage ./Fun1 temp")
}
```

```
$ Rscript Fun1.R 32 
[1] "Hello World"
[1] 273.15
```

Comment: Thank you. That works when I call this function in the terminal. However, when I call it from the R console, I face an error ("cannot find the function"). What could be the reason of this?

Comment: When you start a new R session in the console, you need to load the definition of the function first.  You can do this by calling ```> source("~/tuning1/Fun1.R")```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right. Have had any chance to kindly look at this question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558126/r-function-does-not-return-a-numeric-value)