# R function does not return a numeric value

Tags: r, linux, function, output

I have created a function as bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
targetRunner <- function(temp) {
  cost <- ((temp - 32) * (5 / 9)) + 273.15
  return(cost)
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
if (length(args) > 0) {
  targetRunner(as.numeric(args[1]))
} else {
  print("Supply one argument as the numeric value: usage ./target-runner temp")
}
```

I can flawlessly run this function from the terminal of Linux. However, when I introduce it to the iRace package as the tragetRunner and use `checkIraceScenario(scenario = scenario)` to check that I have properly prepared everything for this package, I receive the following error:

```
...
== irace == The output was:
[1] NA
...
# targetRunner returned:
NULL
```

According to the User Guide of the iRace package, this error occurs only when the outcome of this function is not a numeric value. Would you please let me know why this function does not return a numeric value?

Comment: This function cannot not return a numeric value. However, it can return a numeric vector of length 0 (if `as.numeric(args[1])` is `NULL`) and it can return a numeric `NA` or `NaN` value (if `as.numeric(args[1])` is `NA` or `NaN`). In your case, it appears to return `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is specific to iRace package. Please Tag it accordingly.

I am not familiar with iRace but from the examples provided [1] it looks like the script above must print a simple numeric value. In your case, R printing more text than you want.
Try to use cat(targetRunner(...)) in your if statement.

You should also read carefully the iRace documentation because you are getting 4 arguments as input to the script, not just one, make sure the first argument is the one you want to use for temperature conversion.

[1] https://github.com/cran/irace/blob/master/inst/examples/Spear/target-runner